# How to collect more than 22 event ids with winlogbeat?

Tags: elastic-stack

I've got a task to collect over 500 events from DC with winlogbeat. But windows got a limit 22 events to query. I'm using version 6.1.2. I've tried with processors like this:

```
    winlogbeat.event_logs:
      - name: Security

    processors:
      - drop_event.when.not.or:
        - equals.event_id: 4618
    ...
```

but with these settings client doesn't work, nothing in logs. If I run it from exe file it just starts and stops with no error.
If I try to do like it was written in the official manual:

```
    winlogbeat.event_logs:
      - name: Security
        event_id: ...                
        processors:
          - drop_event.when.not.or:
            - equals.event_id: 4618
    ...
```

client just crashes with "invalid event log key processors found". Also I've tried to create new custom view and take event from there, but apparently it also has query limit to 22 events.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: 1st one started to work from some 6.x.x version